# Is tkinter code written the same for python 2 as it is in python 3?

Tags: python, tkinter

We've been working on a GUI in tkinter and I'm not sure if it is in python 2 or 3. At first I couldn't get it to run until I changed the import statement from "`from tkinter import *`" to "`from Tkinter import *`". It runs but I'm still not 100% sure if the code is written in python 2.

(I couldn't share the code since I was getting an error when I tried to post my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to add this to the top of your files that use tkinter (if you want your program to run in python2 or 3 environments):

```py
try:
    import tkinter as tk # This is the python3 version
except:
    # If an exception occurs in the try block, the except block will execute. 
    # If no errors occur in the try block, the except block is skipped.
    import Tkinter as tk # This is the python2 version
```

Nearly all of the functionality is identical between the two versions of tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tkinter is nearly identical between python 2 and 3. The imports have changed, but other than that there are no significant differences.